# What is the best way doing cross-realm type checking in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, typechecking

I'm currently building a type checking library that supports checking variables from another realm (a.k.a. different context).

For basic types like string and number, I can simply use the `typeof` operator as usual.

For complex types like `Date` instance, the only way to make it work is to use `Object.prototype.toString.call()` method. But this method has its problem, I have to iterate through the prototype chain of the instance if the `Symbol.toStringTag` property was overridden.

The question is, should I iterate through the prototype chain of the instance if the value returned by `Object.prototype.toString.call()` doesn't match in the first time?

Comment: Why can you not use `instanceof`?

Comment: @connexo It's because `instanceof` not work with variables from another realm.